# Cross Slide z-index issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, z-index, slideshow

I'm using [cross slide](http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/) script.

The problem is I can't move the div to the background: slideshow overlapping all other divs. Tried to change z-index: Set z-index 0 to background div, and z-index:2 to all other divs. Still no success. Is there anyway to apply slideshow to the background div?

My css strcture looks like that

```
<body>
  <div id="bg">
  "all stuff goes here"  
   </div
</body>
```

And css for #bg

```
#bg {
 /* Stretch background */
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 z-index:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set css to:

```
#bg {
 /* Stretch background */
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 z-index:0;
}

#test {
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    z-index:5;
    width: 120px;
    margin-top:5px;
}
```

and html to:

```
<body>
    <div id="bg"></div>
    <div id="test">"all stuff goes here"</div>
</body>
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AgLe5/).

Answer (score 0):

Take it to the background with `z-index: -1`

Comment: do you read my question at all? "Tried to change z-index: Set z-index 0 to background div, and z-index:2 to all other divs. Still no success. "

Comment: Yes I did, you said you changed z-index value but you didin't say anything about negative values. Try adding position: absolute;

Answer (score 0):

instead of making z-index:0 or -1 to your "bg" id, make all other content z-index to 99 or more than that. so your "bg" will be back of your slides.

Answer (score 0):

Do you observe the (complex) rules for stacking contexts, positioning, and z-index correctly?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index/The_stacking_context

Comment: problem is in js https://raw.github.com/tobia/CrossSlide/master/jquery.cross-slide.js

Comment: Sure, but what does the generated HTML look like, and how is it styled with CSS?

Comment: pay attention to selected answer